# Not able to get the value for the xml tags using xsl - (xsl:value-of)

Tags: html, xml, xslt

XML Code:

```
  <complextype name="submission">
    <sequence>
      <file-audit-data></file-audit-data>
      <submission-period-from-date>01/01/2014</submission-period-from-date>
      <submission-period-to-date>12/31/2014</submission-period-to-date>
      <aco-gpro></aco-gpro>
    </sequence>
    <attributeGroup ref="submissionAttributeGroup" />
  </complextype>
```

XSL Code:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//complextype[@name='submission']"> 
  <td width="40%"><u>From date:</u><br/><xsl:value-of select="submission-period-from-date"/><br/></td>
  <td width="40%"><u>To date:</u><br/><xsl:value-of select="submission-period-to-date"/><br/></td>          
  </xsl:for-each>
```

It is not at all going inside for-each, Please help me in understanding what is causing the issue...

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT? In particular, can you show the template match. Ideally we need enough to recreate the problem. Also, is your XML sample truly representative of what you are using? If not, does your actual XML have namespaces (as indicated by "xmlns" on elements)? Thanks.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>       
     <xsl:value-of select="ns1:submissiondate"/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-interface-submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="gov/cms/pqrs/patient/v1">  
      <submissiondate>asdfdsfsdf</submissiondate>      
</web-interface-submission> -------- This is my XML file

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XML and XSLT as it is hard to read it in comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You xsl:foreach work on 'complextype' node, not on 'sequence' node. Try this: "<xsl:for-each select="//complextype[@name='submission']/sequence">"

Comment: After adding the below code, html is not rendering only values are getting displayed:<xsl:template match="/ClinicalDocument">, before it was this "<xsl:template match="/">"

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: If i try mi code the result is: "From date:01/01/2014To date:12/31/2014"